# Loop over objects in ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, ggplot2

I have multiple data frames in the same format and I want to create multiple curves in the same graph using ggplot. Each data frame has data from a year, from 1956 to 2019. For example:

```
Year1956 <- data.frame(prob=c(5, 10, 20, 30, 100), Qmcs=c(1000, 500, 50, 10, 5))
Year1957 <- data.frame(prob=c(1, 3, 25, 35, 100), Qmcs=c(800, 600, 100, 50, 30))
```

It is possible to plot these multiple objects in the same graph manually, where ... would be Year1958 to Year2018

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=Year1956, aes(x=prob, y=Qmcs))+
  geom_line(data=Year1957, aes(x=prob, y=Qmcs))+
  ...
  geom_line(data=Year2019, aes(x=prob, y=Qmcs))
```

Is there a way of doing this in a loop, since there are many data frames? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of showing how to loop over a list of dataframes to generate separate `geom_line`, my answer will instead show how to combine similarly structured data.frames and do it all in a single `geom_line`.

Let's presume we have a series of data.frames with the pattern `"Year"` + `number`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

Year1956 <- data.frame(prob=c(5, 10, 20, 30, 100), Qmcs=c(1000, 500, 50, 10, 5))
Year1957 <- data.frame(prob=c(1, 3, 25, 35, 100), Qmcs=c(800, 600, 100, 50, 30))
```

We can systematically gather all the data.frames that satisfy the pattern by looping over the years and using the `get()` function.

```r
years <- c(1956:1957)

mylist <- lapply(setNames(nm = years), function(i) {
  get(paste0("Year", i), mode = "list")
})
```

Lastly, we can combine all those data.frames together and keep track of what year we had by using the `idcol` argument in `data.table::rbindlist()`. Plotting the data then will be simple.

```r
df <- data.table::rbindlist(mylist, idcol = "year")
df$year <- as.numeric(df$year)

ggplot(df, aes(prob, Qmcs, group = year)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>